# React native, Firebase notification quit state listener re-fire after refreshing app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using React native `0.65.1` and `"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "12.8.0"`, and have `messaging().getInitialNotification()` listener for cases that the app opened from quit state by notification.
Besides that, I have multiple languages in the app, and in case a user changes his language from RTL to LTR (or the other way around...), I'm calling

```
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'

RNRestart.Restart()
```

The problem is, that in case the user started the current session of the app (only from a quit state) by a notification, if he will change the language in the same session in a way that causes refresh, the `getInitialNotification` listener will be fired again (with navigation or UI manipulation that's not needed).

Searched through the docs if there's any way to delete a message after the first time of listener runs, couldn't find any, and don't have any other idea how to encounter this issue (open as well for a suggestion on how to fix it from the other end of `Restart`, if someone has an idea how to switch from RTL to LTR in another way or with equivalent method/library that won't cause this issue).

(`onNotificationOpenedApp` (from background state) and `onMessage` (on foreground state) don't create this issue...)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you maybe use [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) in your app?

Comment: @Kapobajza no, and how it's relevant? Any idea to solve it with using?

Comment: It could maybe be relevant because of [this](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3469) issue. But since you're not using `react-native-splash-screen`, then it's not relevant in your case. Have you maybe tried making a release, instead of a debug build, and tried to reproduce the issue? Because I have faced similar problems but only when using the debug build.

Comment: @Kapobajza I don't have the same issue at all

Comment: Perhaps, you can consider not restarting the app on changes to the user preferences. You could store the user's preferences  such as the language in a React.Context and have components consume from that context for internationalization.

Comment: The need for restart is not just for the texts, its also for the layout